# Mandatory "before asking" for Pandas questions

Tags: discussion

I'm often browsing the [Pandas tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) on Stack Overflow, a lot of these questions seem to come from new Python users, and they often don't post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

I stumbled upon this post: *[How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)*

Would it be a good idea to force people reading this post before submitting their question?

Comment: Post quality is *always* going to be an issue. Plenty of people "read" the [tour] before posting and then go on to post something that is specifically identified as "bad". The best thing you can do if link them to the post in the comments, and (if needed) downvote and/or vote to close.

Comment: Good luck making that happen - if they don't want to, they'll move around a bit to trick the system or just not read it. Vote to close as a dupe of the canonical instead (provided it falls under no MCVE as well); it means a badge holder can single-handedly close it (potentially with one preceeding vote or flag). It's the closest you're gonna get

Comment: Maybe not make it mandatory, but I think a lot of new users are not even aware of what makes a good question. Maybe a little pop-up that displays "if you want to have good answers, read this post" before posting.

Comment: That is not a bad idea. Similar to how a specific [explanation pops-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i09DE.png) when tagging `regex`. That would be definitely nice to have, but sadly as others said, I doubt will make a significant change. Most people will just ignore, and I think forcing is not a good way to go

Comment: almost nobody reads the tour, so simple give them a friendly notch in the right direction, and if no change close it

Comment: I don't see how the pandas tag itself is special, other than seemingly attracting a huge fraction of people-not-willing-to-program. What is the benefit in giving pandas askers even more things to read through? If people aren't aware how to ask good questions, then the general how-to-ask-good-questions should apply, no?

Answer (score 5):

No, because there's no way to guarantee that they *didn't* already read it and tried to apply it.

English may also not be their first language so there could be some language barrier nuances to the issue as well, which would preclude the successful comprehension of what's in that post.

A lot of what made Stack Overflow the platform that it is is its ability to immediately ask a question to address a specific pain point.  Gonna have to tell you that until the company starts taking steps to address the part where people can just ask a question at that level, anything *we* want to do or suggest isn't going to be all that actionable or feasible.  We'll just have to clean up the mess.